# Can't find folder after mv command

Tags: path, mv

I was working on a backend, and decided to make a git repository for the whole app. After cloning into my home directory, this is the list of commands:

```
~$ mv PartySpotBackend /PartySpot
mv: cannot move 'PartySpotBackend' to '/PartySpot': Permission denied
~$ sudo !!
sudo mv PartySpotBackend /PartySpot
~$ ls
node_modules PartySpot tmp
~$ cd PartySpot/
~/PartySpot$ ls
LICENCE README.md
~/PartySpot$ ls -a
. .. .git .gitignore LICENCE README.md
```

The entire `PartySpotBackend/` directory seems to have disappeared. Is there any possible way to recover or find it? This is on Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have moved the directory into `/` as `/PartySpot`, not into `~/PartySpot`.

You were at your home directory `~` i.e. `/home/$USER/` while sending the file and you have sent it to `/PartySpot` (under root directory `/`), not the `~/PartySpot` directory in your home directory.

As you have used `sudo mv PartySpotBackend /PartySpot`, the destination `/PartySpot` starts with `/` meaning its an absolute path.

In a nutshell, look at `/PartySpot`.